# After deploying a Windows Form Application the printer gives error "tmpPrint.print is denied"

Tags: c#

I am using C# Windows Form for this project.
My problem is when i'm running the application on VS my application prints to the printer, which is POS Printer, normally without any problems. After the deployment and when I try to print I get this error:

[image]

```
PrinterUtility.PrintExtensions.Print(bytesValue, "\\DESKTOP-G51FFAS\80mm Series Printer");
```

this is the line I'm using to print. Can anybody help?

UPDATE:
Here's the details from the exception:

```
    ************ Exception Text ************
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Default Company Name\Cashier\tmpPrint.print' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.InternalWriteAllBytes(String path, Byte[] bytes, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(String path, Byte[] bytes)
   at PrinterUtility.PrintExtensions.Print(Byte[] bytes, String port)
   at Cafe_Template.Sallah.printing()
   at Cafe_Template.Sallah.printButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

I gave permission to every file in the project. The printer is connected via USB to the same PC that has the application but I only found the above way to connect it to the application; I connected it as a network printer and gave to it the path `\\\DESKTOP-G51FFAS\80mm Series Printer`

Comment: Do you still get the error when you start the (deployed) application as admin?

Comment: @Odrai I don’t get the option to run it as administrator when I right click on it